# How to avoid document.write in an external script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to avoid or replace the document.write loading through an external script. here the link `//lv.adocean.pl/files/js/aomini.js`

I tried this (answered by someone) but it didn't help.

```
document.write=function(s){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    var lastScript = scripts[scripts.length-1];
    lastScript.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", s);
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try `document.write = function() { }`

Comment: @freedomn-m what does this comment mean?

Comment: @freedomn-m unfortunately, i can't edit the file

Comment: Add it as the first line in a `<script>` tag as the first entry in your own html's `<head>` *before* you load any other script

Answer (score 2):

I will try to explain @freedomm-m's suggestion, hoping to be clear.

To re-assign `document.write`, which returns a function, to an *"empty function"*... could do the trick to avoid the "normal" execution of `document.write`.

By *"empty function"*, I mean a totally valid function, but doing strictly nothing.

So after that re-assignment, every times the `document.write` function will be called anywhere in the document, instead of executing the `write` function found under the `document` object's property, it will execute that *"empty function"* (read: Nothing).

Here is a demo of that principle applyed on the `console.log` function, just to keep it simple and be obvious in this demo here.

```js
console.log("I am executing...")
console.log("I am executing too...")

// Assing an empty function
console.log = function(){}
console.log("I am NOT executing!")
console.log("I feel useless now... :( ")
```

Now to "temporarly" avoid a function execution, you have to store it in another variable in order to "undo" the re-assigment...

```js
console.log("I am executing...")
console.log("I am executing too...")

// Assign the function to a variable
let tempStorageOfTheDisabledFunction = console.log

// Assing an empty function
console.log = function(){}
console.log("I am NOT executing!")
console.log("I feel useless... :( ")

// Restore the original function
console.log = tempStorageOfTheDisabledFunction
console.log("Yeah! I'm back in play!")
console.log("I feel better.")
```

So now, what fredomm-m suggested to try is:

```
<script>document.write = function(){}</script>
<script src="path-to-external-js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain in detail